# Combo box id in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

Can I find the `id` of a combo box in JavaScript, not its value?

jsp file code

```
function ChangeColor(colors) {
    var partcolor = (colors.options[colors.selectedIndex].value);

    if (partcolor=="black"){
      document.getElementById("colorRow").style.backgroundColor = 'black';
     } 
    else if(partcolor=="brown")  {
     document.getElementById("colorRow").style.backgroundColor ='brown';
    }   else if(partcolor=="yellow")  {
     document.getElementById("colorRow").style.backgroundColor ='yellow';
    }
}
```

java file code

```
public String getColor(String colorName) {
mySB.append("<select onchange=\"ChangeColor(this);\" style=\"font-size:0.8em;\" id=\"").append(colorName).append("\" name=\"").append(colorName).append("\">")
            .append("<option value=\"\">&nbsp;</option>");

}
```

How can I print the id of combo box here?

Comment: HTML doesn't have combo boxes (which are a *comb*ination of a select menu and a text box). It's just a select, or dropdown menu

Comment: Seems you set the ID to nothing here: id=\""

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the entire list of controls in the form and get their id's.
Based on your need, you can differentiate the control in quest using the type,name etc.

```
function DisplayFormControl()
{
var str = '';
var elementList = document.getElementById('FormId').elements;
for(var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++)
{
alert(elementList[i].type);
alert(elementList[i].name); 
alert(elementList[i].value);

} 

}
```